# authorizationController delegate didCompleteWithAuthorization what type is the param authorization: ASAuthorization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios13

I work under Delphi, and I try to understand what exactly is the `authorization: ASAuthorization` param in the `didCompleteWithAuthorization` delegate of `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`

```
// ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate function for successful authorization
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential { 
        // Create an account in your system.
        let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
        let userFirstName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
        let userLastName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName
        let userEmail = appleIDCredential.email

        //Navigate to other view controller
    } else if let passwordCredential = authorization.credential as? ASPasswordCredential {
        // Sign in using an existing iCloud Keychain credential.
        let username = passwordCredential.user
        let password = passwordCredential.password

        //Navigate to other view controller
    }
}
```

what I don't fully understand here, it's what exactly mean

```
if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
```

and

```
} else if let passwordCredential = authorization.credential as? ASPasswordCredential {
```

does it's mean that `authorization.credential` in inherited from both types: `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` & `ASPasswordCredential` or that `authorization.credential` is just a pointer that can be any kind of object and we just need to cast this pointer? How to know with type of object the `authorization.credential`? In with scenarios `authorization.credential` return an `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in apple docs,
credential is the information provided about a user after successful authentication.

> Every credential is inherited from / conforms to ASAuthorizationCredential.
>
> There are 3 conforming types : ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, ASAuthorizationSingleSignOnCredential and ASPasswordCredential.
>
> ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential : A credential that results from a successful Apple ID authentication.
>
> ASAuthorizationSingleSignOnCredential : A credential that results from a successful single sign-on (SSO) authentication.
>
> ASPasswordCredential : We can use this to create a credential  with a given user name and password.

You can typecast it according to different ways the credential has been created. If the resulting credential is from Apple ID authentication, then the cred can be typecasted to ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.

Comment: but when the delegate will return me a ASPasswordCredential ? how can I do to have a ASPasswordCredential  in my delegate ? right now I see only ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential

Comment: You can initialise a ASPasswordCredential manually or if you want an example, this is returned while  performing keychain credential sharing.

You can also use this while creating a login mechanism which uses username and password.

Comment: sorry i not understand :( how to do exactly to have a ASPasswordCredential  returned IN my delegate?

Comment: @loki was you able to understand how to return ASPasswordCredential in the delegate? I am looking for a casa of use. I am not able to get it returned in Juice app for example.